# free memory outside a void function where it is allocated

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have a void function

```
void foo(int *ptr) {
   //trying to allocate memory to hold 5 ints
   ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*5):
   //I loop ptr and assign each with a value i =0 to 4;
}
```

In the main function I have this lines

```
int main() {
    int *num;
    //I called the function 
    foo(&(num));
    free(num);

   return 1;
}
```

I get munmap_chunk() invalid pointer error. I did try to dig in more information, but I could not figure this out. I know it will be basic for those who work in c. I was thinking I am passing by reference and it should work, but it is not. I am new to C, and so far has been a headache.

Comment: What you pass to `foo()` ( `int**`) and what the type of argument that `foo()` (`int*`) expects don't match. Didn't get any warning messages from your compiler? You probably meant to use `void foo(int **ptr) { *ptr = malloc(...); ...}`

Comment: @P.P if you look main function I passed pointer, an address that point to an int

Comment: @user1986244 Actually, you passed the address of a pointer. A pointer to a pointer. `foo()` should be receiving an `int **`.

Answer (score 7):

`ptr` is a local variable, his lifetime ends with the function, you need a pointer to pointer in order to alter `num` in `main`

```
   void foo(int **ptr) {
       //trying to allocate memory to hold 5 ints
       *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*5);
       //I look ptr and assign each with a value i =0 to 5;
   }
```

Comment: It is not meant to be private messaging, but I would be happy to contact you. I really need more insight as I took the course in C. If you are willing I would be happy leave my email

Comment: @user1986244 - I think you mean AlterMann, not me; he's a little more useful :^) On SO, you can chat with other users via [chat rooms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187426/how-do-i-chat-with-another-user-on-stackoverflow). Unfortunately you do need 100 rep to start a chat with someone, but you'll be there soon.

Comment: `but what I am passing is *num, just a pointer`, no,  `num` is a pointer, but using `&` (address of) with a pointer results in a pointer to pointer.

Comment: @Alter sorry I kept messing your name, and thanks for the explanation. I wanted to email someone and ask briefly than just posting here. Understanding the basics of how pointer works is good, and I am still trying to grasp.

Comment: @user1986244, to understand the basic of pointers the C FAQ is a good start: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/index.html

Comment: thanks, and I have just added more question in another post. These are things I struggle with

Answer (score 1):

For starters the function foo is declared like

```
void foo(int *ptr);
         ^^^^^^^^
```

that is its parameter has type `int *`. While you are calling the function like

```
foo(&(num));
    ^^^^^^
```

where its argument has type `int **` because the variable num is declared like

```
int *num;
```

The compiler should at least issue a message that the types are not compatible.

You need to define the function the following way

```
void foo(int **ptr) {
         ^^^^^^^^^
   //trying to allocate memory to hold 5 ints
   *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*5):
   ^^^^
   //I loop ptr and assign each with a value i =0 to 4;
}
```

In this case the function call will be correct and as the original pointer is passed by reference it will be changed after calling the function.

As for the original function definition

```
void foo(int *ptr) {
   //trying to allocate memory to hold 5 ints
   ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*5):
   //I loop ptr and assign each with a value i =0 to 4;
}
```

then its parameter is a local variable of the function that keeps a copy of the argument. Any changes of the local variable that is of the copy of the original argument does not influence on the original pointer itself. After exiting the function the local variable (parameter) `ptr` will be destroyed.

Comment: I think you answered a question I just asked Alter. Thank you. I was wondering I passed just pointer with *num, but adding & has made it **num, and my function definition did not reflect that.

Comment: @user1986244 The call of the function is correct if you are going to change the original pointer declared in main. That is the variable should be passed by reference. However the function definition is incorrect because the function does not accept the pointer by reference. So it changes only its local variable (pointer)  that is its parameter.:)

Comment: @thank you, if I am allowed I could email you. Really three four hours and days such problems.

Comment: @user1986244 Sometimes even very qualified programmers can not find an evident mistake during hours.:)