# passing pointer to function and accessing it outside

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am trying to concatenate two string literal pointers, and store them in a third string which dynamically allocate memory to fit the two string and finally add and print out the string char. I could not print the string outside the function.

```
 //Here is the function
    void join(char ptr1, char ptr2, char **ptr3) {


        char tempStr[strlen(strPtr1) + strlen(strPtr2)+1];
        strcpy(tempStr, ptr1);
        strcat(tempStr, ptr2);
        *ptr3 = (char*)malloc(strlen(tempStr));
        strcpy(ptr3, tempStr);

        printf("%s\n", ptr3);
   }
```

in the main I have these variables

```
char *str1 = "print "; char *str2= "out"; char *str3;

join(str1,str2,&(str3));

printf("%s",str3)://segmentation fault occur here
```

I have asked similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702957/free-memory-outside-a-void-function-where-it-is-allocated) about pointer manipulation, and I still struggle with such concepts.

Comment: `void join(char ptr1, char ptr2, , char **ptr3) {` should be `void join(char *ptr1, char *ptr2, , char **ptr3) {`

Comment: `*ptr3 = malloc(sizeof(tempStr));
        strcpy(*ptr3, tempStr);`

Comment: It's obvious you don't really understand pointers. Read a tutorial, book or watch done videos. You'll be wasting your time "trying to make it work" until you understand what a pointer is and how to use it. Good luck!

Comment: `strPtr1` and `strPtr2` typo

Comment: (this is not his real code, it won't compile and definitely won't run into a segfault, don't bother commenting on coding errors)

Comment: @Amit you are right, and I try to make things short for readability

Comment: @BLUEPIXY thank you I did not add * inside the strcpy, and that solved my problem

Comment: @Alter , excuse the typo I edit the code before I posted it, and I made a mistake

Comment: Rolled back. This is no live-editing community. Once you have an answer, you must not change the question if that leaves the answer without or with wrong context! Instead, append a properly marked edit to your question if you want to clarify something.

Answer (score 1):

If this is C, you are neglecting to account for the '\0' at the end of the string.  Try this

```
void join(char* ptr1, char* ptr2, char** ptr3) 
{
    char* result =  (char*)malloc(strlen(ptr1) + strlen(ptr2) + 1);

    strcpy(result, ptr1);
    strcat(result, ptr2);
    *ptr3 = result;
}
```

Also why not just return the new string instead of passing in a reference to ptr3?

Comment: refer updated question please, and I think now issued solved

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your posted code is that the line

```
    *ptr3 = (char*)malloc(strlen(tempStr));
```

should be

```
    *ptr3 = (char*)malloc(strlen(tempStr) + 1);
```

The reason for that is the same as why you needed to use `+1` in the line:

```
char tempStr[strlen(ptr1) + strlen(ptr2)+1];
```

You can simplify the function by not creating `tempStr` as a temporary object.

```
void join(char *ptr1, char *ptr2, char **ptr3) {
    *ptr3 = malloc(strlen(ptr1) + strlen(ptr2) + 1);
    strcpy(*ptr3, ptr1);
    strcat(*ptr3, ptr2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue you're having is that you are declaring your ptr1 ad ptr2 as chars instead of pointers.

Any reason you can't use sprintf()?

```
char join(char *s1, char *s2){
    char new_string[80];         // Assuming you know the max size
    sprintf(new_string, "%s%s", s1, s2);
    puts(new_string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiler warnings are not fully enabled.  With a good compiler and warnings well enabled, the compiler would have warned.  This saves you time and avoids unnecessary posts.

```
void join(char *ptr1, char *ptr2, char **ptr3) {
  ...
  // warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' from incompatible pointer type 
  strcpy(ptr3, tempStr);

  // Code should have been
  strcpy(*ptr3, tempStr);
```

---

Some coding ideas: Consider the following that takes advantage of code paying the price to find the string lengths once, no need to do so again.

```
// As ptr1,ptr2 not changed, use const, it's less restrictive calling
// and potential for additional optimizations.
void join(const char *ptr1, const char *ptr2, char **ptr3) {
  size_t len1 = strlen(l1);
  size_t size2 = strlen(l2) + 1;

  *ptr3 = malloc(len1 + size2);
  // Check for allocation success
  if (*ptr3)) {
    memcpy(*ptr3, ptr1, len1);
    memcpy(*ptr3 + len1, ptr2, size2);
    printf("%s\n", *ptr3);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two immediate problems here:

1. You are not allocating space for the null terminator at the end of the resulting string:

   ```
   *ptr3 = (char*)malloc(strlen(tempStr));
   ```

   should be

   ```
   *ptr3 = (char*)malloc(strlen(tempStr) + 1);
   ```
2. You are passing the wrong thing to strcpy.

   ```
   strcpy(ptr3, tempStr);
   ```

   should be

   ```
   strcpy(*ptr3, tempStr);
   ```

I suspect the second one is what is directly causing your crash, since it will likely result in the string pointer (`str3` in `main`) getting overwritten with the start of the string, and also overwrite other random stack memory.